# How do you submit a Gutenberg plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, block-editor

I'm sure this must have been asked and answered, but, I've searched here under "submit" and "commit" and a bunch of other things, and I seem to be missing the right words.

I'm probably a week or two away from being ready to submit my first plugin. It's a new block. The [developer information](https://wordpress.org/plugins/developers/) says it needs to be in a subversion repository. But, all of the Gutenberg blocks seem to be in Github. Also, they're primarily developed in ESNext, and so you have to do a build process before they're compatible with almost anything.

Is there a link somewhere on how to "submit" a new block? Also, what does "submission" entail? Is there a place to get initial feedback / review?

How does one go about submitting their first Gutenberg plugin?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

On WordPress' [Detailed Plugin Guidelines](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-org/detailed-plugin-guidelines/) page, I found a link to the [Block Specific Plugin Guidelines](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-org/block-specific-plugin-guidelines/).

I would recommend you read both before you [add your plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/developers/add/).

**Edited to add:** re: Subversion; it appears that you initially [upload your plugin as a zip file](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-org/plugin-developer-faq/#where-do-i-submit-my-plugin). If & when your plugin is approved, WordPress will provide a Subversion repository to you, which you will be expected to use as the canonical location for plugin updates. (This doesn't stop you from using Github or some other spot in your development workflow, but any official updates *must* go to your WordPress Subversion repo.)